# Simplifying conditional statement android

Tags: android, if-statement, simplify

I have a method with few conditional statements. I have added the if conditions so I can avoid my NPE crash. Is there any way I can simplify the if conditions where I have added the non-null check?

```
 private void addComplementaryProductToBasket(String productId, String comboName) {
        Product product = ProductComboUtils.getProductById(productId);
        if (null == product) {
            LOG.info("Product does not exist in ProductComboUtils, fetching from DB");
            product = getProduct(productId);
        }
        if (product != null){
            product.setPrice(BigDecimal.ZERO);
            product.setCurrencyCode(currentBasket.getCurrencyCode());
            // Ensure to add comboName with purchase, this
            currentBasket.addToPurchase(product, comboName);
            int numberOfComplementaryProducts =
                    currentBasket.getPurchaseLineItemForProduct(product.getProductId()).getNumberOfComplementaryProducts();
            currentBasket.getPurchaseLineItemForProduct(product.getProductId()).setNumberOfComplementaryProducts(
                    ++numberOfComplementaryProducts);
        }else
        {
            CrashUtil.logNonFatalException("Product instance is null for productId: " + productId);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You check twice the opposite thing  `product == null` and  `product != null`. The else is the same condition as the first if ( `product == null`)

Comment: @AxelH no ... he obtains the product again

Comment: Not exactly @AxelH, there is a call `product = getProduct(productId);` so it has another chance to be null or not null.

Comment: do you want to check if product is null everytime?

Comment: ProductComboUtils.getProductById(productId); and    getProduct(productId); are same??

Comment: @jimmycarr yes, I noticed that a bit late (well, not alone ;) ) ... I have edited my answer about that.

Comment: I think you are going in a wrong way @Baabidi if as per the conditon 1. if product is empty then you are getting the product by product = getProduct(productId); statement and moving to next if. but if you get null in product = getProduct(productId); method also how can you get a product?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to simplify the if conditions in this example if you want to maintain the logic of checking `ProductComboUtils` first and then fetching from the DB.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are getting the value from two sources, I would simply create a methods to do it with the checks (Utlis or DB).

```
public Product getProductTest(String productId){
    Product product = ProductComboUtils.getProductById(productId);
    if (null == product) {
        LOG.info("Product does not exist in ProductComboUtils, fetching from DB");
        product = getProduct(productId);
    }
    return product;
}
```

Then you just need to get the value and check the value. If this is `null` then there is a problem and you show the error.

```
private void addComplementaryProductToBasket(String productId, String comboName) {
        Product product = getProductTest(productId);
        if (product != null){
            ....
        } else ...
}
```

Comment: @Selvin, just edit my answer to change the solution, if you are the one that downvote it, please read it again and told me if this is better.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep a separate column for the product information/detail availability.

Add extra column **isUpdated** in your table and keep **0** as default value.

When you reach enough requirement update the column value to **1**

```
public void isProdUpdated(int id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        try {
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null); // selectQuery is your complete query 
        if (cursor.getCount() != 0
                && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            int status = cursor.getInt(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(Const.KEY_IS_UPDATED));
            cursor.close();
            return status;
        }
        cursor.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return 0;
    }
    return 0;
    }
```

Example

```
public Product getTestProduct(String productId){
    Product product = null;
    if (ProductComboUtils.isProdUpdated(productId) == 1) {
        return product = ProductComboUtils.getProductById(productId);
    }else{
        LOG.info("Product does not exist in ProductComboUtils, fetching from DB");
        return product = getProduct(productId);
}
}
```

Before getting product information call the above method with your primary and check value. If it return 1 then go ahead, else prompt user for no info available.

Comment: Then, I don't understand why you are adding a column to his table to simplify a condition statements ...

Comment: I just shared my idea.

Comment: You don't get it. How are you ending with this idea with the information we have here ? Could you be more specific about how this is going to help, I might simply miss the genius behind this !

Comment: I hope that example is simplified one. Correct me if am wrong.